# How to set "Hide in list view" on SSRS report programatically

Tags: reporting-services

With **ReportingService2005 - CreateReport method** the report can be created on report server. But how to set the value of **Hide in list view check** box to true?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got it finally :-)
In the case that someone needs it:

```
var properties = new Property[1];
var hidden = new Property { Name = "Hidden", Value = "True" };
properties[0] = hidden;

Warning[] warnings = ReportingService.CreateReport(fileNameWithoutExtension, ssrsFolder, true, fileContents, properties);
```